# How to add a Dropdown to a Google Form using the Script Editor?

Tags: drop-down-menu, google-apps-script

I am new to Google forms and I am trying to add a Dropdown to my form. However adding a Dropdown is not one of the features of google forms (yet) OR if it is, I have not been able to activate it.

I am trying to add a Dropdown to the form using the Script Editor, so my immediate question is :-
- How would I link the script and the Form?

I have found the following discussion the closest to what I am looking for so far, but it does not hit the bulls eye
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/fLNCa09zzV4

I'd love your input on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `addListItem()` method:

[Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#addListItem())